# custom array sort to force certain values to start or end of array

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have an array

```
$ar = ['apples','blueberries','end','pears','dragonfruit','oranges','start','durian','lychee','rambutan','pineapple','end','start'];
```

I want the array in some order (lets say alphabetic order for this argument), but with the values 'end' on the tail and 'start' on the head of the array.

```
function cmp($a,$b) {
    if ($a == $b) return 0;
    if ($b === 'start') return 1;
    if ($b === 'end') return -1;
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($ar,"cmp");

echo implode(", ", $ar);
```

How do I sort so that values matching a specific value will end up at the head or tail of the array, but other values will sort based on other criteria (e.g. numeric, alpha, etc)

Comment: you're already close, right now you're missing the comparison on `$a` as well, `if ($a === 'end' || $b === 'start') return 1;` and do the reverse on it as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is how your cmp function should be. Just a couple of if statements introduced.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {

    if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ($a === 'start' ) {
        return -1;
    }

    if( $b === 'start' ) {
        return 1;
    }

    if ($a === 'end' ) {
        return 1;
    }

    if ($b === 'end' ) {
        return -1;
    }     

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_diff` with `sort`, `array_push` and `array_unshift`

```
 $elements = ['start','end'];//start & end elements array
 $rest     = array_diff($ar, $elements);
 sort($rest);//Sorting of the rest items
 array_push($rest, $elements[1]);//Push end element  
 array_unshift($rest, $elements[0]);//Push start element
```

You can use `rsort($rest)` for descending order.

Live Example : https://3v4l.org/GnotC

Comment: hmm, except this has changed the length of the array. sometimes duplicates in the array are possible and valid.

Comment: @frumbert you can use `arrau_unique` , for example `array_unique(array_diff($ar, $elements))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$ar = ['apples','blueberries','end','pears','dragonfruit','oranges','start','durian','lychee','rambutan','pineapple','end','start', 'end', 'banana', 'yellow'];

function cmp($a, $b) {

    if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ($a === 'start' ||  $b === 'end' ) {
        return -1;
    }

    if( $b === 'start' || $a === 'end') {
        return 1;
    }


    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1; }

    usort($ar,"cmp");

    echo implode(', ', $ar);
```

Hope this will help you